# Oracle instantclient Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' MacOS Monterey M1

Tags: php, oracle, macos-monterey, instantclient

I have issues installing instantclient locally for php 7.4

For installing instanclient, i follow this instruction:

```
cd ~/Downloads

curl -O https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/mac/instantclient/198000/instantclient-basic-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.dmg
curl -O https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/mac/instantclient/198000/instantclient-sdk-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.dmg
curl -O https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/mac/instantclient/198000/instantclient-sqlplus-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.dmg

hdiutil mount instantclient-basic-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.dmg 
hdiutil mount instantclient-sdk-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.dmg
hdiutil mount instantclient-sqlplus-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru.dmg

/Volumes/instantclient-basic-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru/install_ic.sh

hdiutil unmount /Volumes/instantclient-basic-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru
hdiutil unmount /Volumes/instantclient-sdk-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru
hdiutil unmount /Volumes/instantclient-sqlplus-macos.x64-19.8.0.0.0dbru

sudo mkdir -p /opt/oracle
sudo mv instantclient_19_8/ /opt/oracle

pecl install oci8-2.2.0
```

After that i get this error:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8.so' (tried: /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/oci8.so (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/oci8.so, 0x0009): symbol not found in flat namespace '_OCIAttrGet'), /opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/oci8.so.so (dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/oci8.so.so, 0x0009): tried: '/usr/local/oracle/product/instantclient/19.8/lib/oci8.so.so' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/lib/php/pecl/20190902/oci8.so.so' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/oci8.so.so' (no such file), '/usr/lib/oci8.so.so' (no such file))) in Unknown on line 0
```

Anybody get it working on MacOS Monterey with M1 chip!?

Comment: On M1, you will almost certainly need to use an x64 PHP binary, similar to how Node.js users do it: https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1349

Comment: @ChristopherJones Any instructions on that?